# Function application (word problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, applications

The problem:

[image]

My work so far:

$3=log(\frac{A}{A_0})$--->$10^3=\frac{A}{A_0}$

$\frac{A}{A_0}=1000$

(Am I done there?)

Plugging it in:

$M=log(\frac{1900000}{1000})$

$10^M = \frac{1900000}{1000}$

$M=3.278753601$

I know this is wrong because for it to be 10 times as strong it would have to be a 4.0

EDIT: I realize that $A_0$ can't  1000 because $A_0$ Is supposed to be the smallest measurable quake.

Comment: I know what I did is wrong, but here was my logic: Find the intensity of a 3.0 (I got 1000) Then plug that in, and multiply it by 1900 (1900000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it correct that $\frac{A}{A_0}=1000$ for a quake of magnitude $3.0$. Now you want to find the Richter value of a quake $1900$ times as strong as this, so you take $$\log{(1900\cdot1000)} \approx 6.28$$

Your division by $1000$ is unnecessary. It makes it as though a magnitude $3.0$ earthquake is the basis of the Richter scale, making it the new $0$ point.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\frac{A}{A_0}=1000\quad\Rightarrow\quad A_0=\frac{A}{1000}
$$
then $A'=1900A$.
$$
\begin{align}
M'&=\log_{10}\left(\frac{A'}{A_0}\right)\\
&=\log_{10}\left(\frac{1900A}{\frac{A}{1000}}\right)\\
&=\log_{10}(1900000)\\
&=\log_{10}(1.9\times10^6)\\
&=\log_{10}(1.9)+\log_{10}(10^6)\\
&\approx6.27875
\end{align}
$$